# Android: Last line of textview cut off

Tags: android, layout, textview, layout-inflater

I have a horizontal `LinearLayout` containing a `TextView` followed by a `Spinner` next to it. This `LinearLayout` is dynamically inflated multiple times in a fixed vertical `LinearLayout` contained within a `RelativeLayout`.

The problem is that since I switched from `Theme.light` to `Theme.holo.light`, the last line of the `TextView` gets cut in half. This happens when the dynamic text is long and spans more than one row.

[image]

I have been able to fix this by adding bottom padding to the horizontal `LinearLayout` containing the `TextView` and `Spinner`.

This does not feel like a fix, but more of a hack. Can someone please give me some advice on how to properly fix this?

I have also read some other questions, but none seem to help.

Horizontal Linear layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:text="TextView"/>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Relative layout where above layout is dynamically inflated at Linear Layout with id ll2_7:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/relLayoutButtonNext"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView1" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView10"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingRight="30dp"
                android:text="2.7" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView11"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView10"
                android:text="@string/question2_7" />


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll2_7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView11"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView11"
                android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">
            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**EDIT:**
Here is the complete layout xml for above:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        style="@style/question_section_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/question2_header" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relLayoutButtonNext"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/bottomBar"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp"
        android:paddingLeft="50dp"
        android:paddingRight="50dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonNext"
            android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:onClick="nextStep"
            android:text="Next Section"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonPrevious"
            android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:onClick="previousStep"
            android:text="Previous Section"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>


    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/relLayoutButtonNext"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView1" >



        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView10"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingRight="30dp"
                android:text="2.7" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView11"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView10"
                android:text="@string/question2_7" />


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll2_7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView11"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView11"
                android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView10"
                android:layout_below="@+id/ll2_7"
                android:text="2.8" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/ll2_7"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView10"
                android:text="@string/question2_8" android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll2_8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_below="@+id/ll2_8"
                android:text="2.9" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/ll2_8"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView10"
                android:text="@string/question2_9" android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll2_9"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView10"
                android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_below="@+id/ll2_9"
                android:text="2.10" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/ll2_9"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView10"
                android:text="@string/question2_10" android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll2_10"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView7"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView10"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_below="@+id/ll2_10"
                android:text="2.11" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView9"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/ll2_10"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView10"
                android:text="@string/quesiton2_11" android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll2_11"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView9"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView9"
                android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView12"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView8"
                android:layout_below="@+id/ll2_11"
                android:text="2.11.1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView13"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/ll2_11"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView10"
                android:text="@string/question2_11_1" android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll2_11_1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView13"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView10"
                android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">

            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: try with removing  android:paddingBottom="20dp"

Comment: Try padding over the textview and linear layout margins may also give a nice hand

Comment: LinearLayout is really problematic when used horizontally. Instead use the ConstraintLayout. See. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48677954/630668

Answer (score 68, accepted):

I've encountered the same cut-off issue as shown at the screenshot. It is caused by the baseline alignment in the horizontal `LinearLayout`. `TextView` and `Spinner` have different baselines due to font size difference. To fix the issue it is needed to disable baseline alignment for the layout by setting:

```
android:baselineAligned="false"
```

or in the code:

```
layout.setBaselineAligned(false);
```

Comment: I wish I could up-vote this 100 times! I've wasted sooooo much time in the past few days on this issue, and your answer was my solution! I didn't realize what was going on for so long because it is so hard to debug the view hierarchy on Android. Thanks so much!!!

Comment: This was the solution to my issue, in addition to Rynardt's answer. Thank you!

Comment: This is the correct answer and it point out the reason why error happened. Thanks.

Comment: This is huge tip for situations like this. Not bad at all. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you so much. So, this is actually a bug, right?

Comment: Angga Arya S, No it is not a bug. Just the layout's default alignment setting leads to confusion in case if element text sizes are different and there is a multi-line text.

Answer (score 271):

I applied a `LayoutGravity` to the TextView item:

```
android:layout_gravity="fill"
```

Comment: perfect, tnx, +1; note that many layout_gravity values helps, eg. center_vertical

Comment: Where this doesn't work, adding a padding value of "1sp" should work. I create a style extending `@android:style/Widget.TextView` and add the following lines: `<item name="android:gravity">fill</item>` `<item name="android:padding">1sp</item>`

Comment: why this problem happens just with arabic text ?!

Comment: The answer here alone didn't work for me at first because my TextView, which was wrapped in a LinearLayout with a checkbox and a few other things, had the height of fill_parent instead of wrap_content.  Changing just the height to wrap_content didn't work for me, I had to also use this solution.  Nice work!

Comment: That's just a workaround. The proper solution is to add `android:baselineAligned="false"` to your `LinearLayout`

Comment: Although this seems to work, the correct solution is the one from tomrozb's comment above, or Jusid's answer

Comment: It's 2017, a multi-line TextView may still get clipped with `wrap_content`, and your answer still works. Thanks!

Answer (score 34):

I had the same problem, and found that simply adding

```
android:includeFontPadding="false"
```

the final line of text no longer had its descenders clipped.

Comment: With custom fonts, this might be the perfect fix. This is the only solution that worked for me when using Droid Sans Japanese.

Answer (score 12):

I added some dummy space after text by adding

```
textView.setText(firstString+"\n");
```

I tried all other solution.But this was the only solution worked for me

Comment: this what you call "chepi"

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me, all others didnt do anything. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I found a different solution by extending TextView and adding a custom Class like this:

```
 public class AdaptingTextView extends TextView {

    public AdaptingTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public AdaptingTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public AdaptingTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

        // set fitting lines to prevent cut text
        int fittingLines = h / this.getLineHeight();
        if (fittingLines > 0) {
            this.setLines(fittingLines);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Works great but be careful if you have layout_margin specified on the textview as it can alter the number of fitting lines to be shorter than it should be! I switched to using padding instead of margins and problem fixed

Comment: This works absolutely perfect. By far the best solution i've found.

Comment: This is the correct answer, thanks! To make it a bit nicer and add '...' to the end of the text before it is truncated add `this.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);` in the if statement above, and remove `android:ellipsize="end"` from the XML which for some reason breaks it.

Answer (score 6):

Put the problematic textview inside a framelayout. I think the text view is not calculated correctly because of the sibling view, Spinner.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:text="TextView"/>
    </FrameLayout>
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I had `CheckBox` in same `LinearLayout`. This solved the issue.

Comment: Worked like a charm with a CheckBox situation like @ChintanShah

Answer (score 5):

When this occurs, you should ensure that the `TextView` is not growing larger than it's container -

If a `TextView` is set to `wrap_content` and it's container (or an ancestor container) doesn't leave room for the `TextView` to grow into it can be occluded.

If that's not the case, it's also possible the `onMeasure()` of the `TextView` sometimes doesn't correctly measure the tails of letters, non-latin characters or the effects from text being italic. You can correct for this by setting a global style for your `TextView` so it will be picked up without needed to change your entire code base:

Ensure that you're application/activities use a custom theme like so:

```
<style name="Custom" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light">   
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/Custom.Widget.TextView</item>
</style>

<style name="Custom.Widget.TextView" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView"> 
    <item name="android:gravity">fill</item>
    <item name="android:padding">1sp</item>
</style>
```

The answer by @Rynadt was really helpful in getting to the above stage. Setting the gravity of the Text inside the View ensures on some devices that occlusion never takes place (The text is correctly fitted inside the view), on others a helping hand with padding of an sp value, ensures that the tails et al are accounted for with a TextSize specific value.

Answer (score 5):

My solution was close to the accepted one, but I had to change it to

```
   android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
```

instead. Otherwise the other rows would have been stretch as well with added line breaks at random places. For example, the biggest row had 4 lines, so another row was changed from

`this is a testphrase`

to

```
thi
s is
a testph
rase
```

Answer (score 4):

try with removing android:paddingBottom="20dp"

from

```
 <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp" >
```

Comment: The padding there is actually not related as there are additional items contained within this relative layout with the padding. I removed them for easier reading of this post. See edit in question.

Answer (score 4):

`getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener` does not work in a recycler view. If you're using a recycler, use `View.addOnLayoutChangeListener`:

I found that the ellipsizing I defined for `textView` in xml was not always reflected so I programmatically set it before reassigning the text property. This worked for me.

```
textView.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new OnLayoutChangeListener() {
    @Override
        public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom,
                                   int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
            textView.removeOnLayoutChangeListener(this);
            float lineHeight = textView.getLineHeight();
            int maxLines = (int) (textView.getHeight() / lineHeight);
            if (textView.getLineCount() != maxLines) {
                textView.setLines(maxLines);
                textView.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
                // Re-assign text to ensure ellipsize is performed correctly.
                textView.setText(model.getText());
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have this problem and your `TextView` is inside a `RelativeLayout`, try switching the `RelativeLayout` for a `LinearLayout`.

That fixed the problem for me

Comment: This is the only solution which works for me (strange behavior) ! Thx

Comment: How can you simply "switch" from RelativeLayout to LinearLayout? If you have to layout relatively it's nearly impossible to implement with LinearLayout.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a global layout listener for a TextView in any type of ViewGroup.

```
    final TextView dSTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.annoyingTextView);
dSTextView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        dSTextView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

        float lineHeight = dSTextView.getLineHeight();
        int maxLines = (int) (dSTextView.getHeight() / lineHeight);

        if (dSTextView.getLineCount() != maxLines) {
            dSTextView.setLines(maxLines);
        }

    }
});
```

You can read more about it [here](http://blog.jimbaca.com/2016/03/14/global-layout-listener-to-the-rescue-how-to-fix-the-textview-cutoff)

Answer (score 2):

I know it's so late, but this is work like charm for me.
add this code to your `textview`

```
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

Answer (score 1):

I have this same problem, and its very annoying.

It only happens with Arabic text.

If you make the label multi-line and adding a `\n` at the end of your string, it would fix it, but the problem is that there would be a big gap between this label and the object below it, due to the fact that this field now has a new empty line below it.

A custom control can be done to get around that. But overall, this is an annoying bug.

Comment: If you have a NEW question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up) the question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favorite and you will be notified of any new answers.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is very little you can do to get this working by altering the layouts. As I have found that some methods work only in some cases. I think it depends on the entire layout hierarchy and is not a one-size-fits-all solution. I have also noticed that it happens especially when you have a different font that you want to set to the TextView.

A sure shot method that I have experimented and tested is that you can set the font attributes in code after the view is inflated. I am assuming that you have a font in the assets/fonts folder that you want to you.

For eg in a Fragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view, container, false);
    TextView tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
    tv.setText("Insert text that needs to be displayed");
    AssetManager assetManager = getContext().getAssets();
    Typeface typeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(assetManager, "Fonts/OpenSans-Light.ttf");
    tv.setTypeface(typeFace , 0); // 0 is normal font
    tv.setPadding(10,  0, 10, 0); // This is not mandatory
}
```

And in an Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(Resource.Layout.main_activity);
    TextView tv = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
    tv.setText("Insert text that needs to be displayed");
    AssetManager assetManager = getContext().getAssets();
    Typeface typeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(assetManager, "Fonts/OpenSans-Light.ttf");
    tv.setTypeface(typeFace , 0); // 0 is normal font
    tv.setPadding(10,  0, 10, 0); // This is not mandatory
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best workaround for this is to add a dummy View of desired height (i.e. this will add padding itself) at the bottom of your view.

```
<TableRow
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
 android:layout_marginRight="5dp" >
     <View 
       android:layout_width="match_parent" 
       android:layout_height="30dp"/>
</TableRow>
```

Like in my case I added one more table row at the bottom of the view. Hope this could help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Add padding to the bottom of the text view:

```
android:paddingBottom="24dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found a handy solution. I get the number of lines of the TextView after rendering and set the height according to the number of lines. Here is the code.

```
TextView textView = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setText(this.text);
textView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        int linesCount = textView.getLineCount();
        textView.setLines(linesCount);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, this solution worked like a charm.

The height and width of my outermost layout was set dynamically, so the TextView contained within got it's text cut even if I set android:maxLines in my xml (for different devices it was behaving differently).

After trying out different methods, finally I got a solution that fixed my issue.

Textview:

```
public class CustomTextView extends androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView {
    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }
    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
    public CustomTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        // set fitting lines to prevent cut text
        int fittingLines = h / this.getLineHeight();
        if (fittingLines > 0) {
            this.setLines(fittingLines);
            this.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
        }
    }
}
```

xml:

```
<com.myproject.android.customviews.CustomTextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_partner_description"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_small_medium" />
```

Answer (score 0):

create theme as for particular language like style-ar which cut-off textview:

```
<style name="EnnodaCustomTextView" parent="Widget.AppCompat.TextView">
        <item name="android:paddingTop">1dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">1dp</item>
</style>
```

Apply it in you AppTheme to reflect in overall app for padding bottom, as :

```
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/EnnodaCustomTextView</item>
```

Note : create same style name in default styles.xml with no item tags for padding..(where no need of extra padding )

Answer (score -1):

I finally fixed it!

I try to add String to the TextView **in Service** and then call scrollTo(), the last line be cut off!

The scrollTo() should be call in "Runnable", like:

```
private ScrollView mScrollView;
public void scrollToBottom()
{
    mScrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.debug_textview_scrollview);
    mScrollView.post(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            mScrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
        }
    });
}
```

I think it because in the monent of call scrollTo() in service, the update of TextView is not ready.