# Text cut off for TText Controls Delphi xe5 Android

Tags: android, delphi, text, delphi-xe5

Developing for Android via Delphi xe5.Text on TText and TLabel controls are not displaying properly. Seems as if the last line of text is being cut short per character.

This is my issue i believe but not applicable to Delphi xe5
[Android: Last line of textview cut off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11243867/android-last-line-of-textview-cut-off)

Here is a QC report I found describing my issue. 
http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=121356

Note: The workaround listed in the QC report does not work for me because I am dynamically creating a lot of text controls ( thus can not create in design builder ) and changing the autosize property does not do anything for me.

Any work around or way to resolve this issue? Text displays correctly for iOS, but not for Android.

Thanks !

Comment: C/P'ed wrong link. Woops. Fixed now.

Comment: Is this on an actual device, or just the form designer and/or Win32 'mobile preview' build?

Comment: On an actual Android Device. Problem does not occur on Win32, iOS simulator/iOS device.

Comment: Note that [QualityCentral has now been shut down](https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/quality-keeps-moving-forward), so you can't access `qc.embarcadero.com` links anymore. If you need access to old QC data, look at [QCScraper](http://www.uweraabe.de/Blog/2017/06/09/how-to-save-qualitycentral/).