# TextView is cut off at the bottom from ListView

Tags: android, listview, textview

I have a ListView that contains many item.
Items are RelativeLayout like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white">

    ...
    ...
    ...

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDescriptionDetailConnect"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ivImageDetailConnect"
        android:layout_below="@id/tvTypeDetailConnect"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/ivImageDetailConnect"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:textColor="@color/colorDarkGray"
        android:textSize="12sp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

But the TextView `tvDescriptionDetailConnect` is cut off at the bottom when size font settings is too large.
Why ?

[image]

Comment: Because the height of its parent RelativeLayout is fixed. Make it wrap_content and it should work.

Comment: I need to fix height of RelativeLayout to 100dp.
I just want to hide the cut line.
And even with wrap_content, the line is cut.

Answer (score 0):

Since the contents of Relative Layout height is more than 100dp.Replace the Relative layout height  from 100dp to wrap_content. Which will provide the height for the as much as they required.

> android:layout_height="wrap_content"

Comment: As I said to @PraveenSingh, I need to fix height of RelativeLayout to 100dp.
And event with wrap_content, the line is cut.
I juste want to hide the line that is cut.

Comment: Try Jose's method

Comment: Try layout width to match_parent and elippsize to end and i didn't  get why you added layout_gravity as fill.I didn't find any scope of it

Comment: I tried the popular answer of this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11243867/android-last-line-of-textview-cut-off

Comment: add  android:singleLine="true" to your textview or android:maxLines = "1"

Answer (score 0):

You can *ellipsize* the text to avoid cutting off your text or you can change the height to `wrap_content` and use a `minimunHeight` of `100dp`

Comment: Have you tried with `singleLine=true` on your textView?

Answer (score 0):

Give match_parent as height to TextView and then use ellipsize the text to avoid cutting off your text

Comment: ellipsize to "end" ?