# ConstraintLayout not scaling to adjust for various screen sizes

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I have the below Constraint Layout that works well on a `Pixel 4 XL`.
It seems to scale for a number of different devices in AVD when tested.

Albeit, when a friend of mine tried it on `Pixel 5` it appeared all squashed and overlapped. I'm still getting my head around Constraint Layouts and screen scaling and was wondering if somebody could do me a huge favour and cast an eye over the below Layout file to see where I might be going wrong please? Many thanks! Please let me know if you require any additional info/screenshots etc. More than happy to provide them.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical">

 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/minabackground"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
 
 <pl.pawelkleczkowski.customgauge.CustomGauge
    android:id="@+id/gauge2"
    android:layout_width="143dp"
    android:layout_height="143dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="59dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    app:gaugeEndValue="800"
    app:gaugePointEndColor="@color/md_blue_800"
    app:gaugePointStartColor="@color/md_blue_300"
    app:gaugeStartAngle="135"
    app:gaugeStartValue="0"
    app:gaugeStrokeCap="ROUND"
    app:gaugeStrokeColor="@color/md_grey_400"
    app:gaugeStrokeWidth="10dp"
    app:gaugeSweepAngle="270"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/gauge3"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3" />

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/explainguage1"
    android:layout_width="143dp"
    android:layout_height="34dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/syncopatereg"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:text="PRICE VS 24HR L/H:"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/gauge2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/explainguage"
    android:layout_width="143dp"
    android:layout_height="34dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/syncopatereg"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:text="PRICE VS ATL/ATH:"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/gauge3"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2" />

 <pl.pawelkleczkowski.customgauge.CustomGauge
    android:id="@+id/gauge3"
    android:layout_width="143dp"
    android:layout_height="143dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    app:gaugeEndValue="800"
    app:gaugePointEndColor="@color/md_blue_800"
    app:gaugePointStartColor="@color/md_blue_300"
    app:gaugeStartAngle="135"
    app:gaugeStartValue="0"
    app:gaugeStrokeCap="ROUND"
    app:gaugeStrokeColor="@color/md_grey_400"
    app:gaugeStrokeWidth="10dp"
    app:gaugeSweepAngle="270"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3" />

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/priceresult"
    android:layout_width="104dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="9dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/syncopatereg"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:maxLength="5"
    android:text=""
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView3"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView3"
    tools:layout_conversion_absoluteHeight="75dp"
    tools:layout_conversion_absoluteWidth="117dp" />

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/percentageresult"
    android:layout_width="105dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/syncopatereg"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:maxLength="5"
    android:text=""
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView3"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/priceresult"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView3"
    tools:layout_conversion_absoluteHeight="75dp"
    tools:layout_conversion_absoluteWidth="117dp" />

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/dailylow"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/gauge2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:maxLength="5"
    android:text="0.00"
    android:textColor="@color/lightgrey"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/gauge2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/gauge2"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/gauge2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/gauge2"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.491" />

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/dailyhigh"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/gauge2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:maxLength="5"
    android:text="0.00"
    android:textColor="@color/lightgrey"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/gauge2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/gauge2"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/dailylow"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/gauge2"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.491" />

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/slash"
    android:layout_width="16dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/gauge2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="/"
    android:textColor="@color/lightgrey"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/gauge2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/dailyhigh"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.555"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/dailylow"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/gauge2"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.491" />

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/alltimelow"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/gauge2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:maxLength="5"
    android:text="0.00"
    android:textColor="@color/lightgrey"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/gauge3"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/gauge3"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/gauge3"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/gauge3"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.491" />

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/alltimehigh"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/gauge2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:maxLength="5"
    android:text="0.00"
    android:textColor="@color/lightgrey"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/gauge3"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/gauge3"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/alltimelow"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/gauge3"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.491" />

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/slash2"
    android:layout_width="16dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/gauge2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="/"
    android:textColor="@color/lightgrey"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/gauge3"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/alltimehigh"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/alltimelow"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/gauge3"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.491" />

 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/largeroundedbox2"
    tools:visibility="visible" />

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/marketcap"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="52.39dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="150dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/syncopatereg"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text=""
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/circsupply"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="52.39dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="44dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/syncopatereg"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text=""
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/volume"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="52.39dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="96dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/syncopatereg"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text=""
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/volumeheader"
    android:layout_width="197dp"
    android:layout_height="52.39dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="96dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/syncopatereg"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="24HR VOLUME:"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/circsupplyheader"
    android:layout_width="197dp"
    android:layout_height="52.39dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="44dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/syncopatereg"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="CIRC SUPPLY:"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.028"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/marketcapheader"
    android:layout_width="197dp"
    android:layout_height="52.39dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="150dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/syncopatereg"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:text=""
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="66dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView5"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/smallpricebox" />

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/explainprice"
    android:layout_width="228dp"
    android:layout_height="36dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="-1dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/syncopatereg"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:text="CURRENT PRICE + 24HR CHANGE:"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView5" />

 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_width="182dp"
    android:layout_height="67dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView2"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/minapluslogo" />

 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView5"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView4"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/marketdataheader" />

 <com.matthewtamlin.sliding_intro_screen_library.indicators.DotIndicator
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:numberOfDots="2"
    app:selectedDotIndex="0" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a lot of hardcoded large `dp` values.  `width`/`height`/`margins`/`padding` will all result in different outputs per device.  You are on the right track using a `ConstraintLayout`, but you are also not letting it do its job by having all of theses large `dp` values.

For example `imageView2` looks fine, no large `dp` values and its size is effectively defined by what its constrained too.

But looking at `gauge2`.

```
<pl.pawelkleczkowski.customgauge.CustomGauge
    android:id="@+id/gauge2"
    android:layout_width="143dp" <-- You are assuming the screen is this wide.
    android:layout_height="143dp" <-- You are assuming the screen is this tall.
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="40dp" <-- You are assuming you have that much space from the Left.
    android:layout_marginTop="59dp" <-- You are assuming you have that much space from the Top.
    android:paddingLeft="10dp" <-- This I would say is fine its small enough that it wont be a problem along with the rest of the padding.
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    ...
/>
```

Setting small `dp` values for small adjustments is fine and will keep everything looking good across most screens.

But when using the `ConstraintLayout` allow it to place things where they need to go through proper constraints, and then do the fine tuning with the `dp` values.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer and help, it is appreciated very much. I will set to work ending the reliance on hard coded height and width of the items in my Constraint Layout. Out of curiosity, what do I do if I want to resize items relative to how I want them to look in the layout (in comparison to the other items)? Hopefully that makes sense. Many thanks.

Comment: You would use `weights`. Here is an answer that shows you how including a picture of the result.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48677839/how-to-add-different-weight-to-constraintlayout-views

Comment: Thank you. I've marked yours as the answer. I did what you said; removed a lot of the hard coded values, and instead let the constraints do the job with there being only small tweaks here and there. I also used a combo of 'match_parent, 'wrap_content' and a number of guidelines (with percentage selected) in order to scale everything to how I wanted it to look. The end result is testers have reported no overlapping or squashing and everything mostly looks spot on for a number of different devices.

Answer (score 0):

Remove hard code values instead of height and width use padding will scaling for different screen sizes

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).